# How do I upload very large files to MySQL without crashing my server?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have several 50+ MB sized csv files I need to import to my MySQL server. I tried importing one using PhpMyAdmin, and the Apache server crashed. I've tried a couple of windows tools, like MySQL workbench, but found no options for importing csv.

I'm at a loss. What can I do?

Comment: The `LOAD DATA INFILE` solutions given below should also be very easily managed by your MySQL server and so your box won't fall over.

Comment: If you are able to directly connect to sql then id suggest http://www.heidisql.com/ or some other sql client. it has csv import functionality.

Comment: Sounds like you are reaching a limit of either the php.ini conf var upload_max_filesize. Also try dumping the file to a local directory on the server before you write it the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are CSV, right?  Have you tried importing them directly into the MySQL server?  I don't know how the other tools that you've tried do this, but MySQL has a command for importing from text files:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Check [this section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) of the reference manual.

Comment: Worked great! But is there a way to do this for say, an array of csv files? Or perhaps target a folder of csv files? If not, how could I get MySQL to run an sql file with your answer copy-pasted 20-25 times with different paths?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` or `mysqlimport` command. They are the bulk upload tools for MySQL and should be able to handle your file without any problems. You can also turn indexing off before running the command then put it back on afterwards to improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

FTP or SSH the files onto your server.

Then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) to load the files into your database.